# Automatically importing needed modules in eval(...)

Tags: python, import, eval

I want to load an object from file using `eval`. That object is dumped to the file so that it is a valid python expression - all types are given with their fqdn, like this:

```
mod1.Class1(
    attr1=mod2.Class2(a=1,b=2),
    attr2=[1,2,3,4],
    attr3=mod1.submod1.Class3(),
)
```

When I feed this into `eval`, not all of those modules are imported in the scope where `eval` is called, so I get either `NameError: name 'mod1' is not defined` for top-level modules, or, when those are imported, `AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'submod1'` for sub-modules.

Is there a graceful way to handle that? I can parse `NameError`, run `__import__` and re-try `eval`, but I am at loss how to get what went wrong from `AttributeError`.

Could I feed the expression to `compile`, walk the AST and import whatever is necessary? Never worked with the AST though, any example for that?

Note I am **not** interested about security here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `pickle` for this? You can even `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods on your classes to control aspects of the serialization and instantiation. Seems seriously better than doing your own `eval()` thing.

Otherwise, how controlled are the values in your serialization format? I.e. maybe you can just predict what modules are going to be needed.

Comment: I need the data to be human-readable and trivially modifiable. So pickle is out. The values are not so much controlled, and the main package has too many sub-modules in multiple levels.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wedded to using full Python (rather than something more easily parseable like JSON or YAML) for your data, walking the AST sounds fairly feasible. You'd want to implement an [ast.NodeVisitor](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) and keep track of the Attribute nodes visited.